# Is this mantra from vishnu purana ? Vasudeva manārādhya ko mokṣaṁ saṁvyāpasatī

Tags: scripture, vishnu, puranas, mantras, vishnu-purana

Hi all wanted to confirm if this mantra is from Vishnu purana

> Vasudeva manārādhya ko mokṣaṁ saṁvyāpti

वासुदेव मनाराध्य को मोक्षं संव्याप्ति

if so does anyone know its verse number in Vishnu purana?

It roughly translates to `Who can attain liberation without attaching his mind / worshiping Vasudeva.`:

- वासुदेव (vāsudeva): Refers to Lord Krishna
- मनाराध्य (manārādhya): Worshiped by the mind
- को (ko): Who.
- मोक्षं (mokṣaṁ): Liberation or salvation.
- संव्याप्ति (saṁvyāpti): Attainment or accomplishment

Comment: Hi, can you give a rough English translation?

Comment: @Haridasa it roughly translates too: Who can attain liberation without attaching his mind / worshiping Vasudeva .

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is a slighty different version occuring in the [Padma Purana Verse 1.3.38](https://sa.wikisource.org/wiki/%E0%A4%AA%E0%A4%A6%E0%A5%8D%E0%A4%AE%E0%A4%AA%E0%A5%81%E0%A4%B0%E0%A4%BE%E0%A4%A3%E0%A4%AE%E0%A5%8D/%E0%A4%96%E0%A4%A3%E0%A5%8D%E0%A4%A1%E0%A4%83_%E0%A5%A7_(%E0%A4%B8%E0%A5%83%E0%A4%B7%E0%A5%8D%E0%A4%9F%E0%A4%BF%E0%A4%96%E0%A4%A3%E0%A5%8D%E0%A4%A1%E0%A4%AE%E0%A5%8D)/%E0%A4%85%E0%A4%A7%E0%A5%8D%E0%A4%AF%E0%A4%BE%E0%A4%AF%E0%A4%83_%E0%A5%A6%E0%A5%A9):

> वासुदेवमनाराध्य को हि मोक्षमवाप्स्यति ।
> यद्रूपं मनसा ग्राह्यं यद्ग्राह्यं चक्षुरादिभिः ॥ ३८ ॥
>
> vāsudevamanārādhya ko hi mokṣamavāpsyati | 
> yadrūpaṃ manasā grāhyaṃ yadgrāhyaṃ cakṣurādibhiḥ || 38 ||

[English translation of the chapter](https://www.wisdomlib.org/hinduism/book/the-padma-purana/d/doc364123.html). The context is a conversation between Goddess Earth (Pṛthivī) and Brahmā (called Nārāyaṇa, i.e.,—*brahmā nārāyaṇākhyosau*):

> The Earth said:
>
> 33. Salutation to you, the all-existing one; salutation to you, the highest soul; lift me today from this (ocean); formerly I have risen from you. Salution to you, O highest soul; salutation to you, O soul of man.
>
> ...
>
> 38-40a. **For, who would attain salvation without propitiating Vāsudeva?** All that form which can be mentally grasped, the external form that can be perceived by eyes etc. and that which can be defined by intelligence, is your form. I am full of you; you are my support; you have created me (and) I have sought your refuge. Therefore the people call me ‘Mādhavī’ (i.e. of or belonging to Mādhava i e. Viṣṇu).